# typescript file is not compiling in VS2012

Tags: angular, typescript

Typescript is not compiling in vs2012. Added web essential version

[image]

Comment: Fixed image link

Comment: Matt do you have solution of this?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a really old version of web essentials with a new version of TypeScript.

Install newer VS Web Essentials from here : http://vswebessentials.com/download

Comment: after installing this version there is no option in tool->> options->web essential->> typescript  only option is there "Show preview window"